# How can I transfer emails from KMail 4 to Thunderbird 9?

Tags: email, thunderbird, mbox, kmail, maildir

I'm trying to transfer the locally stored emails from KMail 4 on an old computer to Thunderbird 9 on a new computer. I'm aware that KMail uses maildir format and Thunderbird uses some variant of mbox. So I thought I should be able to convert the maildir files into mbox format using some open source tool:

- This [Python script](http://dcwww.camd.dtu.dk/~schiotz/comp/kmail2thunder.html) fails to run because of numerous `OSError`s (different parts of the code make different assumptions about the working directory so it tries to create files in nonexistent directories)
- This [Perl script](http://brunocornec.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/migrating-from-kmail-to-thunderbird/) does nothing - it runs, but the folder it creates is empty
- This [Bash script](http://fixunix.com/kde/93329-mass-convert-kmail-maildir-mailboxes-mbox-format.html) apparently does create the mbox files, though I can't verify 100% that its output is correct.

Then I tried copying the mbox files into Thunderbird's profile directory. When I opened Thunderbird (version 8 with a testing profile, I believe it should work the same), the folders appeared but no messages showed up in them. I also tried importing the mbox files using [ImportExportTools](http://freeshell.de/~kaosmos/mboximport-en.html) but the effect was the same: the folders show up in Thunderbird but the messages don't.

I've heard recommendations to use an IMAP server to transfer messages but I'm seeking alternatives because these computers are behind a rather slow internet connection.

Is there a method that actually works which I can use to transfer these emails from KMail to Thunderbird 9 without sending them over the internet?

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: KMail is on Kubuntu, I forget which version but it might be 9.10, and Thunderbird is on Windows 7.